# Find the intersection (vector) of two 2D planes

Tags: linear-algebra

Wall #1 is defined by [1,1,6]^T and [2,0,7]^T.  Wall #2 is defined by [1,1,2]^T and [3,2,-1]^T.  Perform the steps that a CAD program might do to find a vector which represents the corner created where these two walls intersect.

Hint: the left nullspace is perpendicular to the column space.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.  This problem has me confused.  Maybe because of the 'hint' given.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming coordinates given are for vectors parallel to walls.

Let $A$ be the cross product of the first two vectors. This is perpendicular to the first wall.

Then make $B$ similarly for the second wall.

Then $A\times B$ is in direction of the intersection of the two walls.

Alternatively assume the first wall is $ax+by+cz=0$ then fit the first two vectors in it ie.

$ 1a+1b+6c=0$ and $2a+0b+7c=0$  solve these to get the equation of first wall $W_1$.

Then do the same for the second wall

Solve $1a+1b+2c=0$ and $3a+2b-1c=0$ to get equation of second wall $W_2$.

Finally put the two equations $W_1$ and $W_2$ together and solve the resulting system.
the solution will be the equation of the 
line of intersection.

Comment: ~  I looked through every related question asked on this website to see how they worked this type of problem.  There are a lot of references to 'direction'. ??  I am required to use linear algebra (matrix manipulations) to do my work.

Comment: It's pretty common to geometrically interpret vectors as oriented line segments, or weighted directions. Is there something you find unusual with this notion?

Comment: @Muphrid~I don't remember ever coming across it in my math studies.

Comment: That right?  Well, you might find it useful here. For instance, the walls you talk about are planes that contain all directions that are linear combinations of the defining vectors. The orthogonal complement to each plane is the plane's normal vector, calculated through the cross product.

Comment: @Muphrid~ Given that I'm working with linear algebra....is it safe to assume that I can calculate the null space for each wall and then the column space (hence, the hint).  Then solve the matrix of the column spaces?